# Mi código imprime datos de ciclos anteriores

Tags: c

Este programa se supone que está en proceso de ser una calculadora que evalúa una operación matemática ingresando una cadena, sin embargo, aún no está terminado.

Antes de ello, me encargué de validar que se ingresaran símbolos correctos (números y operadores), que los signos de agrupación estén completos (paréntesis que se abre es paréntesis que se cierra) y que no comience con una multiplicación o división. Por ejemplo, que no empiece con `*3` o `/3*4+6` porque sería una operación inválida, sino que sea `3*3` o `4*5+6` para que no marque un error de sintaxis.

```
/* Realizar un programa en C que realice lo siguiente:
    - Recibir del usuario una cadena que contiene una fórmula matemática con digitos (del 0 al 9) y operadores binarios.
    - Evaluar si la fórmula esta bien formulada (WFF)
    - Calcular la fórmula y imprimir en pantalla el Resultado.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cant 100

void Validar_Caracteres(char *t);
void Validar_Parentesis(char *p);
void Validar_MultDiv(char *q);
void Resolver(char *r);

int main(){
    bool ok;
    char expresion[cant];

    printf("    L A   C A L C U L A D O R A   D E   Z U L E\n\n");
    printf("Ingresa una expresion matematica. Puedes introducir\n");
    printf("   -Numeros del 0 al 9\n");
    printf("   -Operadores como:\n\t*Suma             +\n\t*Resta            -\n\t*Multiplicacion   *\n\t*Division         /\n");
    printf("   -Parentesis como signo de agrupacion\n\n");
    scanf("%s",expresion);
    Validar_Caracteres(expresion);
    Validar_Parentesis(expresion);
    Validar_MultDiv(expresion);
    Resolver(expresion);
    return 0;
}

void Validar_Caracteres(char *t){
    while (*t!='\0'){
        if (*t>='(' && *t<='9');
        else{
            printf("Ingresaste caracteres invalidos\n");
            main();
        }
        t++;
    }
}
void Validar_Parentesis(char *p){ //Valida que todos los parentesis o signos de agrupacion esten cerrados
    int abre=0, cierra=0;

    while (*p!='\0'){
        if (*p=='(') abre++;
        if (*p==')') cierra++;
        p++;
    }

    if (abre==cierra);
    else{
        if (abre>cierra) printf("Te falta cerrar %i parentesis", abre-cierra);
        else printf("Te falta cerrar %i parentesis", cierra-abre);
        printf("\n");
        main();
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void Validar_MultDiv(char *q){ //Valida que la expresion no comience o termine con '*' o '/'
    while (*q!='\0'){
        if (*q=='*' || *q=='/'){
            if (*(q+1)=='\0' || *(q-1)==NULL){
                printf("Error de sintaxis\n\n");
                //system("@cls||clear");
                main();
            }
        }
        q++;
    }
}

void Resolver(char *r){
    int cuenta=0;
    while (*r!='\0'){
        //printf("%c ",*r);
        cuenta++;
        r++;
    }
    printf("Hay %i caracteres\n", cuenta);
}
```

El problema es que al ejecutar el código, mi apuntador en el apartado "resolver" (el cual claramente aún no está hecho) sigue contando lo que salió en ciclos anteriores, donde se supone hubieron errores y ya no deberían de estar ahí :(

¿Qué podría hacer?

[image: Añado una foto de lo que NO DEBERIA SALIR (donde dice "Hay 2 caracteres")]

Comment: A modo de guía: ¿te has dado cuenta que estás anidando llamadas a `main()`? Como es lógico, conforme se vayan resolviendo el control volverá a la función que la llamó. A veces esto se hace dentro de un `while`, por lo que el bucle continuará con su siguiente iteración cuando se le devuelva el control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Estás llamando de manera recursiva a `main()`, por lo que cuando `main()` finaliza devolverá el control a la función que la llamó. En muchos casos la llamada se realiza dentro de un bucle `while`, que seguirá con su siguiente iteración cuando retome el control.

La mejor solución a tu problema es que no llames a `main()` para repetir el mensaje de introducción de datos, si no que sea un bucle `do .. while()` que se repita mientras los datos no sean correctos.

Para convertir tus funciones de validación deberás cambiar el tipo del valor de retorno, por ejemplo, de `void` a `int` para que devuelvan, por ejemplo, un valor `0` si la validación fue correcta y `-1` si falló.

De modo que el bucle `do .. while` quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
do {
  /* Tu código mostrando información y solicitando la expresión */
  /* ... */
  /* Se repetirá el bucle mientras alguna validación no sea correcta */
} while (Validar_Caracteres(expresion) != 0
  || Validar_Parentesis(expresion) != 0
  || Validar_MultDiv(expresion) != 0
);
```

Las comprobaciones deben estar de tal forma que fuercen la repetición del bucle, no una llamada anidada a `main()`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con solo una de las funciones de validación adaptadas:

```
/* Realizar un programa en C que realice lo siguiente:
    - Recibir del usuario una cadena que contiene una fórmula matemática con digitos (del 0 al 9) y operadores binarios.
    - Evaluar si la fórmula esta bien formulada (WFF)
    - Calcular la fórmula y imprimir en pantalla el Resultado.*/

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define cant 100

int Validar_Caracteres(char *t) {
  while (*t != '\0') {
    if (*t < '(' || *t > '9') {
      printf("Ingresaste caracteres invalidos\n");
      /* Falló la validación */
      return -1;
    }
    t++;
  }
  /* Validación correcta */
  return 0;
}

void Resolver(char *r) {
  int cuenta=0;
  while (*r != '\0') {
    //printf("%c ", *r);
    cuenta++;
    r++;
  }
  printf("Hay %i caracteres\n", cuenta);
}

int main() {
  char expresion[cant];

  /* Repetiremos la petición de expresión mientras no sean válidas las comprobaciones */
  do {
    printf("    L A   C A L C U L A D O R A   D E   Z U L E\n\n");
    printf("Ingresa una expresion matematica. Puedes introducir\n");
    printf("   -Numeros del 0 al 9\n");
    printf("   -Operadores como:\n\t*Suma             +\n\t*Resta            -\n\t*Multiplicacion   *\n\t*Division         /\n");
    printf("   -Parentesis como signo de agrupacion\n\n");
    scanf("%s", expresion);
  } while (Validar_Caracteres(expresion) != 0);
  /* Si llegamos aquí los caracteres son correctos */
  Resolver(expresion);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Estoy 100% convencido de que el estándar prohíbe explícitamente llamar `main` de manera recursiva, pero he sido incapaz de encontrar esa prohibición en [el estándar de C](https://web.archive.org/web/20181230041359if_/http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/abq/c17_updated_proposed_fdis.pdf).